# How to convert oracle.sql.ARRAY to any java collections (for example, to java lists or any)

Tags: java, oracle, arraylist

How to cast oracle.sql.ARRAY to any java collections (for example, to java lists or any others)

Comment: Try not to iterate over `oracle.sql.ARRAY` and add it to arraylist, instead ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
oracle.sql.ARRAY a = ...
String[] strArray = (String[])a.getArray();
List lstArray = java.util.Arrays.asList(strArray);
```